Как сделать, чтобы если пользователь сайта не загрузил свой favicon, то использовать favicon который я загрузил сам
Как сделать, чтобы если пользователь сайта не загрузил свой favicon, то использовать favicon который я загрузил сам в папке backend/web/images/defaulffavicon.png
Распишите пожалуйста полный алгоритм, а точнее действия MVC.
Небольшая часть кода
        if ($model->has_favicon) {
            $favicon_preview[] = $model->faviconPreview;
        }
        if (!empty ($model->has_favicon)) {

            "........."
        }

    } 

Код виджета:

<?= FileInput::widget([
            'name' => 'Company[favicon]',
            'id' => 'favicon-input',
            'options' => [
                'accept' => 'application/favicon',
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'fileActionSettings' => [
                    'showZoom' => false,
                    'showRemove' => true,
                    'showUpload' => true,
                    'showDrag' => false,
                ],
                'allowedFileTypes' => ['image'],
                'allowedPreviewTypes' => ['image'],
                'dropZoneEnabled' => false,
                'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
                'showCaption' => false,
                'showRemove' => false,
                'showUpload' => false,
                'autoReplace' => true,
                'showCancel' => false,
                'maxFileCount' => 1,
                'initialPreview' => $favicon_preview,
                'initialPreviewAsData' => true,
                'initialPreviewFileType' => 'image',
                'overwriteInitial' => true,
                'previewFileType' => 'application/*',
                'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['/media/upload-favicon']),
                'deleteUrl' => Url::to(['/media/delete-favicon', 'company_id' => $model->id, 'type' => 'company-favicon']),
                'uploadExtraData' => [
                    'fileKey' => 'Company[favicon]',
                    'resourceType' => 'company-favicon',
                    'company_id' => $model->id,
                ],
                'layoutTemplates' => [
                    'actions' => '<div class="file-actions">' .
                        '    <div class="file-footer-buttons">' .
                        '        {delete}' .
                        '    </div>' .
                        '</div>',
                ],
            ],
            'pluginEvents' => [
                'filebatchselected' => 'function(event, params) {
                          $("#favicon-input").fileinput("upload");
                      }',
                'fileuploaded' => 'function(event, data, previewId, index){
                          if(data.response && data.response.files && data.response.files.length > 0)
                          {
                              if($("#companyform-favicon_id").length > 0){
                                $("#companyform-favicon_id").val(data.response.files[0].id);
                              } else {
                                $("#company-favicon_id").val(data.response.files[0].id);
                                $("#company-favicon_id").trigger("change");
                              }
                          }
                      }',
            ],
        ]); ?> 


вы точно имеете в виду favicon, а не аватар?

Сам сайт делает страницы компаний и когда пользователь там не выбирает свой favicon в главном разделе , то вместо пустого фавикона,  там подтягивается логотип моего сайта, хотя не должен

Всё правильно, мне нужен именно favicon, ещё раз упоминаю, что данный сайт делает страницы компаний и в главном разделе, где вносится основная информация о непосредственно компании, если пользователь не выберет свой favicon, то подтягивается основной логотип сайта, а мне нужно, чтобы подтягивался пустой favicon, который я хочу добавить, условно: если пользователь не загрузил свой favicon на страницу компании, то использовать этот файл ...\

Наймите программиста

Я не прошу сделать это полностью, я попросил о помощи, чтобы расписать алгоритм действий, который я реализую

Что сложного в действии - if (есть загруженный фавикон) { вывести загруженный фавикон } иначе { вывести дефолтный фавикон }?

"Распишите пожалуйста полный алгоритм" ---> если пользователь сайта не загрузил свой favicon, то использовать favicon который загружен в папке backend/web/images/defaulffavicon.png

<?php
if(!isset(FAVICON_BY_USER)){//обработка если нет иконки
}else{//если есть
}

